# laptop still consumes battery despite being in sleep mode

Tags: suspend, thinkpad

i know that there have been multiple similar questions like this, but so far i haven't found one that supports my system's (ThinkPad E14) BIOS configuration settings. are there any other alternate or specific fixes for this?

edit: it's suspend mode, not sleep

Comment: Run this command `while true ; do date >> testdate ;done` then put your computer to sleep if the `testdate` file has a big jump in time then the program got stop

Comment: Sleep mode is expected to continue using the battery... The *sleep* mode is intended to use *minimal* battery, but if battery used was ZERO the machine would OFF.  If you want battery to be ZERO you turn it OFF or use HIBERNATE, **not** suspend.  You've provided no OS/release details either.

Comment: @guiverc i didn't say i expect it to not lose battery at all, i just meant to say that it uses the same amount of battery it does while not sleeping

Comment: I have the same problem, I have Dell G3. Did you find any solutions yet?